# NoCacheProvider class alternative in Hibernate 4

Tags: second-level-cache, hibernate-4.x, hibernate3

I've just realized that there is no `org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider` class in Hibernate 4 Core packages. Maybe it is deprecated. So is there any alternive for Hibernate 4? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

CacheProvider SPI has been deprecated for quite a long time now (since 3.3 iirc).  `org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory` is the "no caching" equivalent in the new CacheRegionFactory SPI